# User relationship one way relation block and unblock option

Tags: 7, users

Im using user relationship module for twitter like one way relationship ,

But i find any option to block the user from following me and in future.

Only remove option is there to remove and once removed, the user again start following me.

Any option to block the user from following me?

Thanks,
Edie :)

Answer (score 2):

This feature does not currently exist, you can not implement it without hacking the module.

There are feature requests open for this, I suggest have a look at these:

http://drupal.org/node/203364

Comment: so i want to hack into the module huh okie will try